# Refresh html page sections *only* upon database table change (row addition)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have a website where users make bets.

Every time a user makes a bet, a new row is inserted into a mysql table.
I would like to find a way to refresh html page sections (not whole page) only when users make bets (upon row insertions).

For example if user A adds a bet, every other user that has the page open in their browsers (user B, user C, ... user N) will get their page sections refreshed.

Having an ajax call to run every second adds excesive overhead to the server and it eventually hungs it (we have tried it).

Is there a technique in Ajax I am missing? We are using PHP, MySQL, jQuery.

What about frameworks such as angularJS, nodeJS, are there any better at accomplisging what I am trying to do?

Thank you in advance for your constructive positive inputs.

Comment: You're going to want to look up [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use nodejs and socket.io to meet your goal...

Create a socket connection and trigger an event to the client when a new bet inserts into your database, here is an example I have created for you https://github.com/atikassam/mysql-express-socket-example

Comment: For example if user A adds a bet, every other user that has the page open in their browsers (user B, user C, ... user N) will get their page sections refreshed. Will it work like this?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a socket connection for each of your users and then after when a new bet adds, emit an event to all the sockets to notify that your bets are updated and now on client-side, update your data table when the same event is triggered ...

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

You can try this.

Comment: The OP wants sections of the page refreshed, not the whole page.